# Delete successful jobs with Ansible kubernetes.core.k8s module?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm trying to delete Kubernetes successful jobs with Ansible `kubernetes.core.k8s` module.

Job:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: helm-install-traefik-crd-n2gbz
  generateName: helm-install-traefik-crd-
  namespace: kube-system
  uid: 8615f527-e6fa-4d48-af5a-8b087d6d229a
  resourceVersion: '2218'
  creationTimestamp: '2023-02-14T02:35:30Z'
  labels:
    controller-uid: 032b353d-24d7-4e8c-a5a6-f77bbf949a36
    helmcharts.helm.cattle.io/chart: traefik-crd
    job-name: helm-install-traefik-crd
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: batch/v1
      kind: Job
      name: helm-install-traefik-crd
      uid: 032b353d-24d7-4e8c-a5a6-f77bbf949a36
      controller: true
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
```

There are multiple jobs to be deleted, each with different pod names, so I tried:

```yaml
- name: Get pod info
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    api_version: v1
    kind: Pod
    label_selectors:
      - helmcharts.helm.cattle.io/chart: traefik-crd
      - job-name: helm-install-traefik-crd
    namespace: kube-system
```

What is the correct format for `label_selectors`? I could not find any documentation examples.

Ideally, I would like to use `kubernetes.core.k8s_info` and get the pod names with `label_selectors`, then use that list of pod names with `kubernetes.core.k8s` to delete them.

Comment: `I could not find any documentation examples.` => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_info_module.html#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

label and label value should be separated by `=`:

```
    kind: Pod
    label_selectors:
      - helmcharts.helm.cattle.io/chart = traefik-crd
```